# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUE_CERT_LOCALLY error on nextjs <Image/> component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I am using nextjs <image component and I am getting this error `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUE_CERT_LOCALLY`, I have even whitelisted the domain in next.config.js file, below is the image
[image]